# Continuity from below for Lebesgue outer measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\{E_n\}$ be an increasing sequence of subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$, measurable or not. Then  $$m^* \bigg( \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_n \bigg)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}m^*E_n$$

Comment: Okay, I believe you. What is your question?

Comment: Presumably $m^*$ is supposed to be outer Lebesgue measure?

Comment: Sorry @Henning Makholm, My question is how to prove it.

Comment: @ShawnD, yes that's Lebegues **outer** measure.

Comment: You might rename this "Continuity from below for Lebesgue outer measure" or something like that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I got it.

Since $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_n \supset E_n$ for all $n$,
We have $m^* \big( \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_n \big) \geqslant m^*E_n$.
Therefore $m^* \big( \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_n \big)$ $\geqslant $
$\lim_{n\to\infty}m^*E_n$.
So it's clear when $\lim_{n\to\infty}m^*E_n=\infty$.
Then we assume $\lim_{n\to\infty}m^*E_n<\infty$.
For all $\varepsilon>0$ and $n$, there exists $\{I_{n,i}\}_{i\in N_+}$,
a sequence of open intervals in $\mathbb R^n$, covering $E_n$, s.t.

$$m\bigg(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}I_{n,i}\bigg)
\leqslant\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}m(I_{n,i})
=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|I_{n,i}|
<m^*E_n+\frac{\varepsilon}{2^n}$$

by definition and properties of Lebesgue outer measure,
and the L-measurability of open intervals.
Then every $G_n:=\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}I_{n,i}\supset E_n$ is an open set,
and $mG_1< m^*E_1+\varepsilon/2$.
Assuming $m\big(\bigcup_{k\leqslant n}G_k\big)$
$<$ $m^*E_n+(1-1/2^n)\varepsilon$, we have

$$\begin{align*}
m\Big(\bigcup_{k\leqslant n+1}G_k\Big)
&=m\Big(\bigcup_{k\leqslant n}G_k\Big)+mG_{n+1}
-m\bigg(\Big(\bigcup_{k\leqslant n}G_k\Big)\bigcap G_{n+1}\bigg) \\
&<\Big[m^*E_n+\Big(1-\frac{1}{2^n}\Big)\varepsilon\Big]
+\Big(m^*E_{n+1}+\frac{\varepsilon}{2^{n+1}}\Big)-m^*E_{n} \\
&=m^*E_{n+1}+\Big(1-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\Big)\varepsilon.
\end{align*}$$

So $$m\bigg(\bigcup_{k=1}^{n} G_k\bigg)
<m^*E_n+\left(1-\frac{1}{2^n}\right)\varepsilon \quad \text{for}\ n=1,2,\cdots.$$

Finally,

$$
m^* \bigg( \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_n \bigg)
\leqslant m\bigg( \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}G_n \bigg)
=m\bigg( \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{k=1}^n G_k \bigg)
=\lim_{n\to\infty}m\bigg(\bigcup_{k=1}^n G_k \bigg)
\leqslant \lim_{n\to\infty}m^*E_n +\varepsilon
.
$$

Since $\varepsilon>0$ was arbitrary, letting $\varepsilon\to 0$ yields the desired result. $\qquad \square$

Answer (score 3):

Let $\mu$ be a measure on algebra $\mathcal A$ of subsets of $X$.
We will show that the outer measure $\mu^*$ defined as
$$
\mu^*(E) = \inf \left\{ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(A_n) \middle| 
A_n \in \mathcal A, E \subset \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n \right\}, \quad E\subset X,
$$
is continuous from below, i.e. $\mu^*(E_n) \uparrow \mu^*(E)$ if $E_n \uparrow E$, $E_n \subset X$.

Proof. If $m := \sup_n \mu^*(E_n) = +\infty$, then $\mu^*(E) = +\infty$ as well and there is nothing to prove, so we assume $m < +\infty$.

Fix any $\varepsilon > 0$.
For any $n$ we construct such $A_{nm} \in \mathcal A$, that $E_n \subset \bigcup_m A_{nm} =: B_n$ and $\mu^*(E_n) \ge \mu(B_n) - \varepsilon$, where $\mu$ denotes an extension of $\mu$ on $\sigma(\mathcal A)$.

Next, let $C_n := \bigcap_{k\color{red}{\ge n}} B_k$. Obviously, $E_n = \bigcap_{k\ge n} E_k \subset C_n \subset B_n$ and thus,
$$
\mu(C_n) - \mu^*(E_n) \le \mu(B_n) - \mu^*(E_n) \le \varepsilon.
$$
Finally, $C_n \uparrow \bigcup_n C_n$ and $E = \bigcup_n E_n \subset \bigcup_n C_n$.
Therefore,
$$
0 \le \mu^*(E) - \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}   \mu^*(E_n) \le
\mu(\cup_n C_n) - \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}   \mu^*(E_n) =
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \mu(C_n) - \mu^*(E_n) \le \varepsilon.
$$
Since $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary, we get the desired property.

Comment: Note that the problem with the accepted solution (given by OP) is with the inequality
$$
m\left(\left( \bigcup_{k\le n} G_k \right) \bigcap G_{n+1}\right) \ge m^*(E_n)
$$
that might be wrong in general.

Comment: I think the problem is that the OP didn't count all of $m^*(E_n)'$ s in the upper bound and it is impossible to bound the set you mentioned from below so as to obtain the OP's final inequality. $E_n=E_n\cap E_{n+1}\subseteq G_n\cap G_{n+1}\subseteq\left(\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^n G_k\right)\cap G_{n+1}, m$ is monotone and $m^*(E_n)$ is defined as infimum.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am stating the trivial thing, but the Borel sets should be closed under countable union, etc. And if I remember correctly the popular definition of Lesbegue measure allows us to use Borel sets to approach measurable sets. To prove this for Borel set should be more or less automatic, like making standard set manipulations, etc.

You may be interested to read about [the limit superior and limit inferior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior).

Edit: sorry I ignored your condition that $E_{i}$ are not necessarily measurable. Under such condition you may be interested in cutting $\bigcup E_{i}$ into $\bigcup (E_{i}-E_{j})$s. Since the two sets are the same and the second set is a union of separated subsets, you should be able to use subaddivity to prove this.

Comment: I've tried to prove that by cutting $\bigcup E_{i}$ as you suggested, and found that the subaddivity doesn't help.

Comment: I agree,  the result does not follow directly, we need more assumptions.

Comment: @Ace: By subaddiviy we have $m^{*}(U(A_{i}))=\sum m{*}(A_{i})$. Now use $A_{i}=E_{i}-E_{i-1}$. We have $m^{*}(U(A_{i}))=\sum m{*}(A_{i})=\sum m^{*}(E_{i}-E_{i-1})$. But we can prove $m^{*}E_{i}$ to be $\sum^{i}_{j=k} m^{*}(E_{j}-E_{j-1})$. Assume $\lim m^{*}E_{n}$ is finite (or else there is nothing to prove), then the result should easily follows.

Comment: uh...your format isn't displayed correctly.

Comment: @Changwei Zhou: I've copied your comment and edited it so it can be displayed correctly. Here is it: By subaddiviy we have $m^{}(U(A_{i}))=\sum m{}(A_{i})$. Now use $A_{i}=E_{i}-E_{i-1}$. We have $m^{}(U(A_{i}))=\sum m{}(A_{i})=\sum m^{}(E_{i}-E_{i-1})$. But we can prove $m^{}E_{i}$ to be $\sum^{i}_{j=k} m^{}(E_{j}-E_{j-1})$. Assume $\lim m^{}E_{n}$ is finite (or else there is nothing to prove), then the result should easily follows.

Comment: I'm affraid that's what additivity says, instead of subadditivity.

Comment: @Ace: I think you can inverse the arrow by using set arguments.