# Proving NonAdditivity of Outer Measure, when countable subadditivity is proven

Tags: measure-theory, outer-measure

I am self studying measure theory from Sheldon Axler's book **Measure, Integration & Real Analysis**. In page 21 (2.18) the author presents the non additivity of Outer Measure as:

There exist disjoint sets $A$ and $B$ of $\mathbb{R}$ such that:
$$\left |A\cup B  \right | \neq \left |A\right |+ \left|B\right |$$

In the follow up to this, earlier the author has proven easily the property of countable subadditivity of outer measure (2.8).

Suppose $A_{1},A_{2},...$ is a sequence of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, then:

$$\left | \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty }A_{k}\right | \leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left | A_{k} \right |$$

**My question is - isn't 2.18 - i.e. Non Additivity of Outer Measure, is a corollary of property 2.8?**

Comment: Please check my edit. No. From $\left | \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty }A_{k}\right | \leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left | A_{k} \right |$ we can deduce that $|A\cup B|\leq|A|+|B|$ but not $|A\cup B|\neq|A|+|B|$. I assume that $|\bullet|$ in your question denotes some outer measure (not necessarily cardinality).

Comment: Yes, exactly. The wording of 2.18 says "there exist disjoint sets such that LHS not equal to RHS". Fair enough. If we prove less than equal to, we will be proving the existence of cases where "LHS is less than RHS (and thus not equal to RHS)"

Comment: The statement $|A\cup B|\leq|A|+|B|$ is generally true for outer measures. But the existence of disjoint sets $A,B$ with $A\cup B|\neq|A|+|B|$ is not generally true for outer measures. Outer measures exist that satisfy $|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|$ whenever $A,B$ are disjoint (for instance if the outer measure of a set is the cardinality of that set). The statement $|A\cup B|\neq|A|+|B|$ for disjoint $A,B$ can at most be proved for special outer measures.

Comment: I am sure, I am missing something here. 2.18 is a special case of 2.8 with $A_{1},A_{2}$ being disjoint sets (which is okay because 2.8 doesnt impose any condition on this part). But to your point that there exists cases where $A$ and $B$ are disjoint and yet their outer measures are equal - I am also referring to top answer to this question (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/298694/countable-subadditivity-of-outer-measure) which goes into a whole lot of detail that is way above my comprehension , but I fail to see a novelty.

Comment: $|A\cup B|\leq|A|+|B|$ is a special case of 2.18. But 2.8 states something stronger: disjoint sets $A,B$ exists with $|A\cup B|\neq|A|+|B|$. That is at least not true for every outer measure. If $c$ denotes cardinality then $c$ on $\mathbb R$ is an outer measure and $c(A\cup B)\leq c(A)+c(B)$ for every pair $A,B$. But for disjoint sets $A,B$ it is also true that $c(A\cup B)=c(A)+c(B)$.

Comment: Cardinality, I think doesnt satisfy the properties of outer measure - specifically outer measure of countable sets(or finite sets) is zero.  But cardinality is not zero except an empty set.

Comment: An outer measure on a set $X$ is by definition a function $\mathcal P(X)\to[0,\infty]$ that is countably subadditive and sends the empty set to $0$ (see e.g. on wikipedia). Cardinality has these properties.