# How to prove that outer measure $|A|=\lim_{t\to \infty}|A\cap (-t,t)|$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, outer-measure

Let $A\subset R$. Then, $|A|=\lim_{t\to \infty}|A\cap (-t,t)|\tag 1$

$|A|:=\inf\{\sum_j l(I_j): A\subset \cup I_j\},$ where $I_j$'s are open intervals in $\mathbb R$ and $l(I_j)$ is the length of the interval $I_j$, and infimum is taken over all sequences of open intervals whose union contains $A$.

I am trying to prove $(1)$.

I know that $|A|= |A\cap (-t,t)|+|A\cap (-t,t)^c|, t>0$.

Suppose that $|A|<\infty$. Then, it suffices to prove that $\lim_{t\to\infty}|A\cap(-t,t)^c|=0$.

Define $f(t):=|A\cap (-t,t)^c|,t>0$. Then, $f$ is a monotonically decreasing function. So $\lim_{t\to \infty}f(t)= \inf_{t>0} f(t)=p,$ say.

If it is shown that $p=0$, then the proof is complete. Suppose that $p>0$. I don't understand how to get a contradiction from here.

And if $|A|=\infty$, then I don't know how to proceed.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: [The same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4068638/a-lim-t-to-infty-a-cap-t-t-a-subset-mathbbr-t0?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 1):

In your definition of outer measure you should write $A\subset\cup_j I_j$. You’ve also written $\cup$ a few times where you meant $\cap$.

In the case $A|<\infty$, fix a countable indexing set $J$ of open intervals $(I_j)_{j\in J}$ whose union covers $A$ and whose measure is finite. Let $\lambda$ denote Lebesgue measure.

Define $I=\bigcup_{j\in J}I_j$. I know for any $t>0$, $|A\cap(-t,t)^c|\le\lambda(I\cap(-t,t)^c)$. Because $I$ has finite measure and $I\cap(-t,t)^c\supseteq I\cap(-t’,t’)^c$ when $t<t’$, and because the intersection of all $(-t,t)^c$ is empty and has null measure, it follows from continuity of measure that: $$\lim_{t\to\infty}\lambda(I\cap(-t,t)^c)=0$$Giving the claim.

So what if $|A|=\infty$? Hint: can you prove that: $$|A\cap(-t,t)|=\sum_{n\in\Bbb Z}|A\cap(n,n+1)\cap(-t,t)|$$And then take limits?

---

It was requested that we solve this problem without using continuity of measure and $\lambda$. The infinite case follows from the above summation idea, so consider only $|A|<\infty$.

This method is maybe easier too.

Hint: choose a cover of $A$ by intervals whose length-sum is finite. You can extract large finite subcovers from this which cover "most" of $A$ and you can relate that to $A\cap(-t,t)$ for large $t$. The 'error' term can be made arbitrarily small; think about the length-sum of the intervals not in your chosen finite subcover.

> Fix a covering $(I_j)_{j\in\Bbb N}$ of $A$ by intervals where we have $\sum_j\ell(I_j)<|A|+1$. Fix $\epsilon>0$. Because the series is convergent I know for some $j_0\in\Bbb N$, we have $\sum_{j>j_0}\ell(I_j)<\epsilon$. I can find $t_0>0$ so large (why?) that $\bigcup_{j=1}^{j_0}I_j\subseteq(-t,t)$ whenever $t>t_0$. I know that, if $t>t_0$: $$|A\cap(-t,t)^c|\le\sum_{j>j_0}|I_j|<\epsilon$$Which allows me to conclude, given the result $|A|=|A\cap J|+|A\cap J^c|$ for any interval $J$ (this is basically the statement that intervals are Lebesgue measurable).

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the answer. I understand how it follows using continuity of measure. This is an exercise problem from Axler's and by that point, Lebesgue measure hasn't been introduced so I've been trying to do it only using outer measure. But it turns out that the outer measure also follows continuity from [below](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116847/continuity-from-below-for-lebesgue-outer-measure). Thanks for letting me know about the typos too. I have fixed them.

Comment: @Koro I have provided an alternative hint / solution which avoids use of the Lebesgue measure

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understand it now: we can find such $t_0$ because $I_j$'s are only finitely many and therefore we can take $t_0$ to be maximum of L and R, where L is the minimum of left ends of $I_j$'s and $R$ is the maximum of right ends of $I_j$. I have one question though regarding the case when $|A|=\infty$. So we have $A\cap (-t,t)= \cup_{n\in \mathbb Z}(A_n\cap (-t,t)$, where $A_n= A\cap (n,n+1]$ (I think one of the ends must be closed here as we are essentially intersecting $A\cap (-t,t)$ with R). Now, $|A\cap (-t,t)|\le \sum_{n\in \mathbb Z} |A_n\cap (-t,t)|$.

Comment: In the limit condition $t\to \infty$, each term on RHS goes to $0$ (by finite $|A|$ case) but how does one ensure that the sum is also 0 on RHS. And, how does one conclude that the series $\sum_{n\in \mathbb Z}|A_n\cap (-t,t)^c|$ converge? Please treat (-t,t) as $(-t,t)^c$ in my last message. Thanks.

Comment: So in other words: what allows me to interchange the order of limits here: $\lim_{t\to \infty} \lim_{N\to \infty} \sum_{n=-N}^N |A_n\cap (-t,t)^c|?$ If this change of order is allowed, then we are done.

Comment: @Koro We don't need to bother with $(n,n+1]$ because $\{n+1\}$ is null. $|X\cap(n,n+1)|=|X\cap(n,n+1]|$ for any $X$. In my proposed idea I did not mention $(-t,t)^c$ for the $|A|=\infty$ case. That's because $|A\cap(-t,t)^c|$ is always infinite in this case - not easy to deal with. As for dealing with that limit, think about the monotone convergence theorem. Summation = integration over a suitable space. I suspect Axler intended a simpler approach, to be honest, but that was the one that appealed to me most quickly. I haven't yet thought of a more from-basics solution